# How does the compiler know that it is at the end of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Consider the following code in C.

```
char *s = malloc(5);
```

I prompted the user for 4 char input and stored it in `*s`. While the program is working with the string `s` it may know that it is at the end of the string by encountering a `'\0'`.

Now , my problem is:
How does the compiler get to know that it is at the end of the array `i` in the following code?

```
int *i = malloc(5);
```

Comment: It doesn't. In C, this is the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: its just a pointer, after 5 elements it will point to something else

Comment: @TuấnPhạm if by "something else" you mean "Undefined Behavior" then yes, else no...

Comment: Ok,it is up to the programmer to make sure that it isn't going out of the bounds.Then,why the '\0' is given for checking the end of a string??..I'm a beginner ....

Comment: @Comp_sci_student The null terminator is only for strings specifically. For plain arrays, one has to use a separate size counter variable.

Comment: regarding: ``int *i = malloc(5);`  this is defining/allocating 5 bytes from the heap.  that 5 bytes is declared to be a pointer to an integer.  So the statement is incorrect.  It should be: `int *i = malloc( sizeof( int* ) );`  or `int *i = malloc( sizeof( i ) );`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't (have to) know.

In C, the compiler need not know whether you are indexing out-of-bounds, or are otherwise invoking [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), it will simply take you at your word.
Lying to it will have *interesting* consequences, especially as the more optimization you request, the harder it will try to prune the invalid paths. The fastest code is code which isn't there.

---

Now, looking at the specific example of how to determine the size of some memory, C strings aren't a data-type, they are a data-format. Specifically, they are defined as a 0-terminated sequence, which includes the terminator. Whether you have a string, or how you determine what a pointer points to, is up to you.

And as an aside, doing a blanket allocation of 5 bytes for an `int`-array raises a red flag. An `int` is likely bigger than a byte, depending on your implementation. Consider using `sizeof` to ask for space for the number of `int`'s you want instead.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. C does not do bounds checking of arrays. It is up to you as a programmer to ensure you do not access out of bounds data. Doing so results in undefined behaviour (aka bad things).

Answer (score 1):

To be very clear: after saying

```
int *p1 = malloc(5);
```

if you then say

```
p1[0] = 1;
```

you are *probably* okay, *if* on your machine type `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes) or less.  But if you say

```
p1[1] = 2;
```

you are probably not okay: you have probably written to bytes 4-7 of the malloc'ed region, i.e. more than you asked for, and you have committed undefined behavior.  *Anything* might happen: you might store that value `2` without causing any other problems, you might overwrite some other variable or data structure (leading to subtle and difficult-to-diagnose bugs), you might get an immediate segmentation violation or other memory access error, you might corrupt memory in such a way that you get a segmentation violation or other memory access error some time later (which is a *very* difficult-to-diagnose bug).  What you will almost certainly not get is a nice, clear error saying "array overflow".

It's a little easier to explain with a slightly more appropriate allocation.  If you say

```
int *p2 = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

then `p2[0] = 1` is fine, and `p2[4] = 5` is fine, but `p2[5] = 6` is undefined behavior.  Or if you say

```
char *p3 = malloc(5);
```

then `p3[0] = '1'` is fine, and `p3[4] = '5'` is fine, but `p3[5] = '6'` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers here are correct, and this may be not exactly what you asked, I want to add that there is some kind of book-keeping.When writing `int *i=malloc(5);`, somewhere behind the scenes, the length of the array is saved, so you would be able to call `free(i)` without specifying its length.

Note that, in your example, you can store 5 `char` inside the `malloc-ed` space, and then you wouldn't know the string has ended. Basically, when using `arrays` and `malloc`, it's your responsibility as the coder, to not go out-of-bounds

Comment: Well, there generally is such for a general-purpose-allocator. But it's a valid (and sometimes very advantageous) choice to chuck that and make `free()` a no-op, provided the amount of memory which might be re-purposed before program termination is adequately small.

Comment: Not sure I understood, are you suggesting to ignore `free` for small memory allocations?

Comment: I'm saying that accepting the overhead neccessary to be able `free` allocated memory is not worthwhile in all cases, just like `free`-ing memory just before exiting is useless make-work.

Comment: Oh, sure. Nevertheless, the overhead exists

Comment: Unless it doesn't, because you omit the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do, is to save the size of your int array to parse it.

```
 #define ARRAY_SIZE 10

 int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE));
 int i = 0;
 while (i < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
     printf("%d\n", array[i]);
     i++;
 }
```